# Estimate maximum likelihood value of sample size in billiard balls draws

Tags: probability, statistics, statistical-inference, maximum-likelihood, parameter-estimation

There are *N* billiard balls in a basket. The billiard balls are numbered from 1 to N.
Four balls are randomly selected, numbered 3, 4, 6, 11. What is the maximum likelihood estimate for N?
Possible answers are: 8, 11, 13, 17

I think the hypergeometric distribution should be used, but I'm not sure how.
Can someone enlighten me, please? Thanks

Comment: Well, clearly $8$ can't be the right answer... we know that there are more than $8$ balls since we pulled a ball numbered $11$.  Now... which outcome do you suppose would be more likely?  Given that there were $11$ balls we picked the balls $3,4,6,11$?  Or given that there were $13$ balls we picked the balls $3,4,6,11$?  For intuition, compare the probability that we picked balls specifically numbered $3,4,6,11$ out of a collection of $11$ balls versus having picked those out of a collection of a trillion balls.

Comment: Indeed, 8 is clearly ruled out and using intuition, I selected N=13. I thought that having 11 balls and picking exactly the last, would have been too much of a coincidence. I was hoping there was a more mathematically rigorous approach to obtain the answer.

Comment: Picking exactly the number two less than the last given that you have more balls is rarer than picking exactly the last given that you have fewer balls... Yes, perhaps it seems like a surprising coincidence to have picked the last ball, but coincidences happen all of the time.  Given that there are $11$ balls, there are $\binom{11}{4}$ equally likely selections of four balls that could have happened, one of which is the scenario we saw.  Compare this to given that there are $13$ balls, there are $\binom{13}{4}$ equally likely selections of four balls that could have happened, more than before.

Comment: Given that you have $N$ balls, the likelihood is $4!*1/[N(N-1)(N-2)(N-3)]$ (there are 4! ways to arrange numbers in your sequence, and the rest is just the probability of a specific sequence). 8 is ruled out since 11 is already there. Plugging remaining options into likelihood gives $N=11$ as the maximum likelihood estimator (likelihood is monotonically decreasing with $N$).

Comment: cool, many thanks to both of you. if you copy it in an answer, I can vote it and mark it as solved.